# npx create-next-app command not working ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, npx

It is showing this error, i'm using npx still it is showing using yarn, npx is working fine when i'm using it for react app

It should provide me the next app starter

Answer (score 6):

A temporary fix might be "npx create-next-app@latest --use-npm", so that creat-next-app will use npm instead of yarn while installing.