# Error, when running: npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, tailwind-css

when I try to create a new Next.js Tailwind 'App' (with this command: `npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project`) I get the following error:

```
C:\socialmedia3>npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss socialmedia3
Creating a new Next.js app in C:\socialmedia3\socialmedia3.

Downloading files for example with-tailwindcss. This might take a moment.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

Der Befehl "yarn" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden. // This is German and means something like: The command "yarn" is either misspelled or could not be found.
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\jesse\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\efeac22998af9bf2\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:100:3828)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\jesse\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\efeac22998af9bf2\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:100:4207)
    at ChildProcess.e.emit (C:\Users\jesse\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\efeac22998af9bf2\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:100:4062)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.e.emit (C:\Users\jesse\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\efeac22998af9bf2\node_modules\create-next-app\dist\index.js:100:4103)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yarn',
  path: 'yarn',
  spawnargs: [ 'install' ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Best wishes.

Comment: You don't need to install yarn. You can just run the command with `--use-npm` at the end. See [npx create-next-app command not working ENOENT error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71627520/1870780).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the lib you are using via `npx` requires `yarn` to be installed and it is not.

You can install it with `npm i -g yarn`.

Comment: Can you also help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635945/how-to-install-next-js-tailwind-explicitly-with-js Best regards.