# How to install Next.js Tailwind explicitly with .js?

Tags: typescript, npm, next.js, tailwind-css

I created a Next.js project and I only have `.tsx` (TypeScript) as the extension everywhere. I know TypeScript is just extended like Java but I just want `.js` as the file ending. I tried to extend the command (`npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project`) by adding `--js` at the end. Apparently that didn't work. Then I tried to change the endings in the already created project, which just brought me a lot of errors. What can I do? Is this still possible? Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

By running the following command:

```sh
npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss my-project
```

You created a new project from a nextjs predefined template (that you can find [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss), in the nextjs repository).

As you can see, this template comes with typescript files by default. Since you are basically cloning this project, you cannot add a flag like `--js` to convert it to plain javascript.

You can either manually convert the files to javascript, or initialise a normal nextjs app (using `npx create-next-app@latest`, which is javascript only) and then installing tailwind separately (follow [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs)).